# pydev - ide complains about module importing itself

Tags: python, pydev

**NOTE**: I haven't accepted an answer because my real question is why this is being marked as a compile error.  I've voted up @TorelTwiddler answer because he gave a workaround, but I'd like to understand the problem.

---

I have a simple module that contains self-test code.  To facilitate use in an interactive session, the self-test code reloads itself (the module).

This works OK in both PyDev (RunAs) and running in an interactive window (after manually amending `sys.path` and importing); but the PyDev IDE still gives a 'compile' / red-X error on the line

```
import Mod1
```

The reason I `import Mod1` from itself is that the name must be resolvable in whatever context is running `Test()`, in order for the reload to succeed.  For instance, if you import `MyMain` from a fresh interactive window, the call to `reload` would fail without the import, since the name Mod1 is not known.

Is there any way I can fix this?? `Mod1` is one part of a much larger project and having it consistently marked as not-compiling makes development more difficult...

Module with the problem:

```
# Mod1.py
def Test():
    """ 
    run the self-test, but first force a reload of the module under test (this mod)
    """        
    import Mod1      # *****'COMPILE' ERROR HERE******  
    import imp
    Mod1 = imp.reload(Mod1)

    TestImpl()

def TestImpl():
    """
    self test here
    since I reload above, I can change this code and re-run from an interactive window
    this has to be a seperate function for the reload in Test to have an effect on this code
    """ 
    print(input("enter"))
```

Extra bootstrap module only used in PyDev (so I can 'run-as')

```
# MyMain.py
import Mod1
Mod1.Test()
```

PyDev/Project PYTHONPATH (appears correct, this folder is at the root of my workspace).  Since it does actually run in PyDev OK, it is definitely correct?

```
/MyDirectory
```

Thanks!

Comment: one suggestion @TorelTwiddler (thanks) that allows me to suppress the IDE error - I'm using this for now but I don't feel it actually answers the question, since this error doesn't seem valid to me.

Comment: another comment was made that it _always poor form_ to self-import.  My usage case here seems acceptable - can anyone weight in on if/why this convention is universally bad?

Answer (score 2):

If you reload a module within itself you create an infinite loop, because you would reload the module only to reload the module again, and again etc...

In your `MyMain.py` you might be able to do this:

```
import Mod1
reload(Mod1)

Mod1.Test()
```

I guess without further code samples its hard to gauge exactly WHY you must reload the module at all, but if you have to, that should work (without doing it in the module)

Comment: Not sure I agree - I'm reloading from within the function `Test`.  Clearly if you call void f(){f();} (C syntax) you're recursively hosed - but that's not what I'm doing.

When Mod1 is loaded, no additional call to `import Mod1` is made

Comment: It does not go into an infinite loop. Each module is imported once (when you use `import` - of course it's possible to enforce re-importing by calling `reload` or something) and subsequent imports just return a reference to the resulting module object.

Comment: @Snaxib as stated in the OP question, the module reloads itself so that, _in an interactive terminal_ the test can be run after a code change in the module, _without_ having to manually reload the module from the interactive window

Comment: You have a good point, Your not necessarily going to recursively reload the module.  However, it is better form to reload the module from where it is called, rather than within itself.  It just makes more sense.  If it needs to be reloaded, have `MyMain.py` reload it.  You can do conditional reloads, but its better practice (and PyDev wont yell at you) if you reload it from the script that imports it.

Comment: @delnan - technically you are correct; but that should be irrelevant here...  I am not recursively loading the module.

Comment: @Snaxib - please check out the OP again - MyMain.py is only necessary for PyDev to run the test... under PyDev there is no need to reload the module, the IDE is starting with a clean slate anyway.  The manual reload in `Mod1.Test()` exists because it makes it a lot less typing in the interactive window...  There is no need to import 'MyMain` in the interactive window

Comment: @mike Looks like I was wrong; a combination of misunderstanding your requirements and writing a comment, only to realize that comments were submitted while I was writing.

Comment: @mike, I think what you should probably be doing is moving `TestImpl` to a different module. This way, when you want to reload it from `Mod1.py`, you won't have that error. Since reloading from the same module is bad form, move what you're reloading to a different module.

Comment: @TorelTwiddler - A higher-level view of what I'm looking for is to quickly & iteratively re-run a test as modify it and the code it's testing...  In your suggestion the Test code would have the same problem (I'd have to manually reload it when I change it).  Where can I learn more about _'reloading from the same module is bad form'_ - it's not immediately clear to me that this should always be true.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with Snaxib's answer, however if you'd prefer to keep the current format, you can have Eclipse ignore the error by adding `#@UnresoledImport` at the end of your line (hit Ctrl-1 to auto fill it in).

Comment: thanks for this tip; that will help me in the short term.  However, this seems like a problem that should have a real solution.  My PYTHONPATH is correct (at least PyDev will execute my proj OK) and the `Mod1` is in the path... so it should not be throwing the compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a separate answer from the discussion on Snaxib's answer, for formatting.

Have one module that doesn't change, `TestMyStuff` and another that you update with your changes, `TheTest`.

```
#TestMyStuff.py
def go():
    import TheTest
    reload(TheTest)
    TheTest.runTest()
```

and

```
#TheTest.py
def runTest():
    #run my tests and change things often here.
    print(input("enter"))
```

Now, from the iteractive shell, you should be able to run `TestMyStuff.go()`, which will have `TheTest` reload every time it's run.

Comment: If you are correct that self-import is _always_ bad, then I can accept this answer; however I don't see how my use case for it is bad and as such feel I should be able to make the IDE stop complaining (without any hacks).  I added a comment to my post asking for clarification on this style question).  Thanks!

Comment: @mike, To be honest, I have no idea if it's bad form to import yourself. I'll also note that I never said _always_. However, I assume that the people who wrote an IDE for the language I use knows more about the language than I do. Are you looking for a way, using Python, to not have this error, or a way for PyDev to no longer complain about this error? If it is PyDev, then you may need to create a bug report with them.

Comment: I would _EITHER_ want to have PyDev not complain, _OR_ understand why what I did was wrong :) I think you are correct that I need to follow up with PyDev.

Answer (score 1):

I went with the *#@UnresolvedImport* annotation that tells PySide to ignore it. In my case there is no real workaround since when using pickle (im using it indirectly through yaml) the correct import path depends on how a module was loaded. If you want to un-pickle an object from outside a module it will not work if pickling was done from the inside. The self-import gives you that possibility.